# Is it possible to export already installed component in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, components, joomla2.5

I want to export a component that already installed in Joomla2.5 site. I've searched in google, and joomla forums, but not able to to find a relevent solution. Anyone knows how to export an installed component from joomla admin side?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually export by going to /components folder using ftp and copy component that you want to export. Admin component folder is administrator/components. And zip that folder.