# How to export an extension from a developed Joomla website if we have access to Admin Panel of Joomla website and cPanel of hosting?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.4

I have a Joomla Website developed by giving work to freelancers.

It has many modules, plugins and components which were developed.

Now I want to develop another website on Joomla. I want to use those extensions but don't have the installation zip files.

Is there a way to export them or to create them by exporting some files. Id yes - then specifically how?

The question is different from [Is it possible to export already installed component in joomla 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239434) as there they are just asking about exporting a component whereas here the exporting has to extend to plugins and modules as well.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239434/is-it-possible-to-export-already-installed-component-in-joomla-2-5

Comment: Sir, that only asks about component, not modules and plugins. Also - I am asking about Joomla 3.4, not Joomla 2.5 which is already outdated.

Comment: ok, however the method described workls for plugins and modules as well, and works for joomla 3.x as well, you simply go to the folder an make a zip thats all, of course the final zip might need a little tweeking

Comment: I would say it's a little more complicated and depends on how well the developer followed the guidelines for creating extensions. Is there an install file? If so then you are probably fine. If not, you will need to either create one and add it, or use discover install by putting the files in the correct location on the new site.

Comment: @NikosM. please tell me about the tweaking needed if any. What can those tweaking be? I have a template with modules and components but unable to replicate components properly. Also tell me how to mark your comment as an answer. I am new to StackOverFlow.

Comment: the tweeking is that you might need to add xml config file or restructure the folder since an expanded component has another folder structure than the one it has as zipped component (see the tutorial on joomla components for the structure needed). All the files would be there but you would need to move them around, thats all

Comment: Can complicated modules + components, like Unite Revolution Slider also be exported using this method sir?

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool for that: [GreenCape/extension-export](https://github.com/GreenCape/extension-export), called Extension Exporter. It was written for and tested on Joomla 3.8. Unlike other tools, it takes the extensions manifest file into account (especially for folder names).

(Disclaimer: I wrote it)

Answer (score 0):

To nibra's answer:

This is very nice, thank you for sharing.
Remarks:

- after installation, I couldn't enable your plugin, needed to set the $filterForm variable public in InstallerViewManage.php line 64
- I could export my component, then removed, but when tried to install it back, it missed the router.php file, which I did not have on administrator side, so I needed to remove it from the exported installation XML file.
- After that I could install my component successfully, but language file was missing, because my component is in Hungarian and no English language file was set for it.
- Also it would be nice to dump the database tables with the component so I didnt need to export/import separately.

So this will be a great tool after a little manual finetune.
Thank you!

Comment: I added a comment to nibra's answer, I don't know why it is appeared here, sorry

Comment: Hi fmarton, thank you for the feedback! Obviously, you tried the dev version, and not the stable 1.0.0. ($filterForm was added later). As for the language: the included language is determined from the manifest file, there's no preference for en-GB.

However, it would be great, if you added the issues you found to the tracker on GitHub!